# Showing selected listview into dialog

Tags: android, listview

I would like to display selected view into a dialog box without any layout,  is this possible?

Error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

In main activity...

```
MyImageAdapter myImageAdapter = new MyImageAdapter(img);
lvImages.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
lvImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(act);
    dialog.setContentView(parent);
    dialog.show();
```

In custom adapter...

```
public class MyImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return camNames.get(position);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
      ...
      return (ImageView) view
    }
```

Comment: what is `act` means in `Dialog(act);`

Comment: "act" is the activity from the main.

Comment: add this Dialog(YourClassname.this); instead of Dialog(act); i don't no it will work or not. if u add full code i may help.

Comment: the error is triggered by dialog.setContentView(parent);

Comment: add `dialog.setContentView(view);` instead of `dialog.setContentView(parent);`

Comment: ya i tried that too but no luck.  its the same error.